# Prevent line break in a table cell between text and image (JSP)

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a JSP page with text and then an image. I want the text to break normally at spaces, but not before this image -- I want the image to appear on the same line as whatever text comes immediately before it.

I read that the `img` tag does not cause a line break, but somehow it seems to be in this case. I suspect it is because it is within a table cell. Is there a way to prevent the line break before the image?

Since I do want line breaks for other text in the cell, I can't use properties on the table or the cell, and since the text is different at different times fixing the width of the column doesn't help either.

I tried putting `&nbsp;` between the text and the image, but still got a break.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try applying `vertical-align:top` to image containing cell?

```
<td valign="top">Image here</td>
```